# Automatically hide LinqPad query

Tags: linqpad

I wrote a simple tool to decode JWT tokens and I'd like to use it in a similar way as the `Interactive Regex Evaluator`.

Is there a way to either automatically hide a query (e.g., via the `Util` class) or to even register it to something like `Ctrl+Shift+F2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that functionality doesn't exist.

You'll notice when using the *Interactive Regex Evaluator* it's opening the sample of the same name but doing extra work to hide the query panel. Looking at LinqPads code using it's own ILSpy, there's a method called `LINQPad.UI.MainForm.miRegex_Click` and it's calling the method `LINQPad.UI.QueryControl.ToggleFullPaneResults` which does that functionality but unfortunately the method is internal.

If you'd like to suggest the feature head over to the LinqPad forums over at http://forum.linqpad.net/ and make the suggestion. Joseph is good at getting back to people.

Comment: Thanks for investigating this. I created a feature suggestion.